# How to put label and input box on the same line using bootstrap?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched extensively on this site and tried my best, but cannot figure out how to put the label and input on the same line, right now, it displays like this:[label and input box are on different lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s7BN.png)

First, as people suggested, I grouped them using "form-group" class, but no luck. Then I continued to search, some says you should use "col-sm-1" which I tried, no luck, some says you should use "form-control-static", but still no luck. Any help is deeply appreciated!

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div  class="row" id="create_new_spa_form">
        <form method= "post" action ="/purchasing/item_info_new_spa/" onsubmit="javascript: return validate();">

            <div class="span4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="input01">Text input</label>
                <div class="controls col-sm-1">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control-static" id="input01">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

After making edits as ZimSystem suggested, now it looks like this:[part of first label got truncated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f58bA.png)

How can I fix this? Also, how can I adjust the size of the input box? I don't need them to be so wide.

Comment: You seem to be mixing Bootstrap 2 and 3 classes. What version are you using?

Comment: Use this <form class="form-inline"> and read documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: Sorry, it's Bootstrap v2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form-inline` and remove the extra markup around the labels and inputs..

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-inline">
    <label for="input01">Text input</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control-static" id="input01">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01"> 
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>   
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01">          
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/7BrrI0uZiH

From the 2.x docs: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Comment: I just noticed that I have a <div class="tab-content"></div> outside of this form, will this affect the display? I'll try your suggestion right now and let you know.

Comment: This does put the label and input box on the same line. Thanks a lot. But they are not properly rendered in the tab, part of the first label got truncated, I just posted a screenshot in my question to reflect what it is now.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your form

```
class="form-inline"
```

more examples here about the Inline form... http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried, no luck. I literally copied the code from the link you posted but it just displayed on two lines, I guess it's due to I have a tab-content outside of the form.

Comment: This does put the label and input box on the same line. Thanks a lot. But they are not properly rendered in the tab, part of the first label got truncated, I'll post an image in my question soon. Sorry, wrong response. Please ignore.

Comment: It was truncated because that was the only one with a size. Please read the Bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap, put the label and input on the same line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group form-inline">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-4">eReview #</label>
 <div class="controls col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```