# How can I put the label and the input on the same line please?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I put the label and the input on the same line please? **I would like to get please a spacing of 1,5cm between the label and input also.**

By searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277144/how-to-put-label-and-input-box-on-the-same-line-using-bootstrap) I have to use `form-inline` but it doesn't work for put the label and input on the same line.

[image]

Thank you so much for your tests.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <!-- CSS only -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 id="welcome">HTML CSS JS</h1>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
         <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="date">Start date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
               <input name="beginDate" id="beginDate" type="text" class="form-control"
               style="background-color: white;"
               (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDateInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
               <input id="picker1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dp1"
               ngbDatepicker #dp1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="begin.validityDate"
               (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDate($event)"
               style="position: absolute; left: 0; visibility: hidden">
               <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp1.toggle()">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
                  <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     
     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
   <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label for="date">End date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input name="beginDate" id="beginDate" type="text" class="form-control"
         style="background-color: white;"
         (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDateInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
         <input id="picker1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dp1"
         ngbDatepicker #dp1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="begin.validityDate"
         (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDate($event)"
         style="position: absolute; left: 0; visibility: hidden">
         <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp1.toggle()">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
     
 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what it does according to your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <!-- CSS only -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 id="welcome">HTML CSS JS</h1>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
         <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="date">Start date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
               <input name="beginDate" id="beginDate" type="text" class="form-control"
               style="background-color: white;"
               (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDateInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
               <input id="picker1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dp1"
               ngbDatepicker #dp1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="begin.validityDate"
               (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDate($event)"
               style="position: absolute; left: 0; visibility: hidden">
               <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp1.toggle()">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
                  <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     
     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
   <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label for="date">End date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input name="beginDate" id="beginDate" type="text" class="form-control"
         style="background-color: white;"
         (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDateInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
         <input id="picker1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dp1"
         ngbDatepicker #dp1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="begin.validityDate"
         (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDate($event)"
         style="position: absolute; left: 0; visibility: hidden">
         <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp1.toggle()">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
     
 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="input date">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="text" for="Date">
</div>
```

Then make the `input` class `display: flex;`

```
.input {
    display: flex;
}
.input label {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what u want?

https://jsfiddle.net/jkL6crdm/

```
.form-group {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

```css
.form-group {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <!-- CSS only -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 id="welcome">HTML CSS JS</h1>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
         <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="date">Start date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
               <input name="beginDate" id="beginDate" type="text" class="form-control"
               style="background-color: white;"
               (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDateInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
               <input id="picker1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dp1"
               ngbDatepicker #dp1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="begin.validityDate"
               (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDate($event)"
               style="position: absolute; left: 0; visibility: hidden">
               <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp1.toggle()">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
                  <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     
     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
   <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label for="date">End date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input name="beginDate" id="beginDate" type="text" class="form-control"
         style="background-color: white;"
         (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDateInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
         <input id="picker1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dp1"
         ngbDatepicker #dp1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="begin.validityDate"
         (ngModelChange)="changedBeginDate($event)"
         style="position: absolute; left: 0; visibility: hidden">
         <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp1.toggle()">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
     
 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using bootstrap, adding the "d-flex" class to the parent element would do the trick. Like this:

```
<div class="form-group d-flex">
```